# How to send OTP in Django before saving model to database

Tags: python, django, django-views, one-time-password

I am working on a project in Django, but I am having some obstacles.

I have a model, say `Transaction`. What I want is that, when the button to create `Transaction` is clicked, an otp would be sent as SMS to a mobile phone. If the OTP is verified (entered correctly), then the Transaction would be saved into the database. If not, it would not be saved into the database.

All the libraries I have seen, such as `django-otp` are mainly for user authentication.

Can they be used for my use case? Are there other libraries that can do this?

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. If you got the solution please share.